# Eigenvectors of operator on Hilbert space are real and distinct - so what can I say about the operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

I have an operator $A$ in a Hilbert space, and after numerically calculating its spectrum I can see that the eigenvalues are real and distinct. What can I say about this operator with this information?

Does it mean $A$ is compact and self adjoint? Are the eigenvectors of $A$ orthogonal?

Comment: You would need more information to determine if the operator is compact (for example, the only accumulation point can be $0$).  And I don't think having real spectrum is sufficient to show the operator is self-adjoint.  Do you have a particular operator in mind, or is this a general question?

Comment: I have a particular operator but it is very complicated (block matrix composed of several sub-operators each of which is quasi-periodic) so I was hoping it might possess some nice properties when viewed at the abstract level.